# asking SCOTUS to throw out the results

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "asking the Supreme Court to throw out the results" mean "asking the Supreme Court to get rid of the results (that is, deny the results and deem them as illegal)"?

It seems to me that "throw out" is ambiguous: It can either be explained as "ignore (as if the results are nonexistent but not reject them as illegal)" or "reject (them as illegal)". I am not sure.

> Brad Heath tweeted:
> So Texas' Attorney General is literally **asking the Supreme Court to throw out the results** of other states' presidential elections, set aside the millions of votes cast in states that are not Texas and have other state legislatures make Trump president.

Answer (score 2):

> *So Texas' Attorney General is literally asking the Supreme Court **to throw out** the results of other states' presidential elections, set aside the millions of votes cast in states that are not Texas and have other state legislatures make Trump president.*

**throw out** - *to dismiss from acceptance or consideration; reject* [Source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/throw%20out)

Another very related meaning would be:

**throw out** - *to get rid of as worthless or unnecessary* [Source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/throw%20out)

So you can see that both mean to discard the results altogether.